# Why in Python 1.0 == 1 >>> True; -2.0 == -2 >>> True and etc.?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, integer

I want to make condition than number has to be integer. And x == int(x) doesn't help in cases when x == 1.0...
Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be true?

Comment: You mean you want to make sure x is a whole number?

Comment: @Keith Integer is likely appropriate - `1.0` is a whole number as well.

Comment: How is 1.0 a whole number but not an integer?

Comment: @chepner Because it's a float. It is equivalent to the integer 1.

Comment: A float isn't a mathematical definition; it's a way of representing a subset of the real numbers (including integers). Whole numbers have various definitions, but they only differ in which integers to include. If a number is a whole number, it's an integer.

Comment: @chepner This is tagged "python" and not "math theory". Integers in Python are well defined and are from a different domain than floats.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
isinstance(x, (int, long))
```

`isinstance` tests whether the first argument is an instance of the type or types specified by the second argument. We specify `(int, long)` to handle cases where Python automatically switches to `long`s to represent very large numbers, but you can use `int` if you're sure you want to exclude `long`s. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) for more details.

As for why `1.0 == 1`, it's because `1.0` and `1` represent the same number. Python doesn't require that two objects have the same type for them to be considered equal.

Comment: Or if you want to also accept third-party implementation of Python's integer interface, you can do `isinstance(x, numbers.Integral)`. There's `gmpy` for example. Side benefit, it works in Python 3 as well.

Answer (score 5):

Not big on python, but I used this to check:

```
i = 123
f = 123.0

if type(i) == type(f) and i == f:
    print("They're equal by value and type!")      
elif type(i) == type(f):
    print("They're equal by type and not value.")
elif i == f:
    print("They're equal by value and not type.")
else:
    print("They aren't equal by value or type.")
```

Returns:

```
They're equal by value and not type.
```

Comment: @downvoter what's wrong with this answer? It compiles and answers the question.

Comment: Not down-voted by me, but it's probably because checking absolute types is discouraged in Python. It's too precise. It doesn't account for the two integer types in Python 2, or for any subclasses. `isinstance()` is normally what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it's an integer.

```
>>> def int_check(valuechk, valuecmp):
        if valuechk == valuecmp and type(valuechk) == int:
                return True
        else:
                return False

>>> int_check(1, 1)
True
>>> int_check(1.0, 1)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Python converts the integer value into its real equivalent, then checks the two values, and thus the answer is true when checking value equivalence, but if one is checking type equivalence then the answer is false.